# Converting a open street map database to a raster attribute table

Tags: openstreetmap, raster, qgis

I'm new to OSM and analyzing maps in general. My task is to convert a certain area from OSM (which is given in an XML format and can be converted to different types of databases)  to a tensor where two dimensions give the area (to a certain resolution), and the third dimension is the "layers" - eventually getting layered matrices of bits for each possible attribute.

For example, if the area is 2*2 (it could be more or less depending on chosen resolution) and the possible attribute are buildings, trees, and roads, then the tensor would be of 2*2*3: 3 layers of 2*2 matrices for the attributes. Cell (i,j,k) in the tensor is 1 if and only if the attribute k exists in the location i,j on the map.

I tried looking online and using gdal, qgis and I am pretty lost.

Is such a procedure possible?

Comment: Hi, and welcome. I think you'll find people much more able to help if you ask at gis.stackexchange.com.

Comment: crosspost: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340926/converting-an-open-street-map-database-to-a-raster-attribute-table

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experience with rasters, so I can only answer the first part of your quenstion.

Get an OSM-map with the following code:

library( OpenStreetMap )

```
LAT1=52;LAT2=54;LON1=4;LON2=6
#get an openstreetmap
map.osm <- OpenStreetMap::openmap( c( LAT1 - 1, LON1 - 1 ), 
                                   c( LAT2 + 1, LON2 + 1 ), 
                                   zoom = NULL,
                                   type = "https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                                   mergeTiles = TRUE)

#plot with latest version of ggplot2  
ggplot2::autoplot( map.osm )
```

[image]

You can (probably) build a raster using `raster::raster( map.osm )`, since `raster` contains a method for OpenStreetmapObjects